# Linking a ABL table to a UltraWinGrid

Tags: datasource, progress, progress-4gl, ultrawingrid

I have created a table in OpenEdge using ABL. I'm now trying to display the table in a UltraWinGrid. I have been following the information found here:

- http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Articles/ArticleTemplate.Aspx?ArticleID=1034
- http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Articles/ArticleTemplate.Aspx?ArticleID=1037

However these are written in c# and vb so the code is not prefect.

So I have a table called test and I've created a dataset like so

```
 DEFINE DATASET WINTEST FOR TEST.
```

but i want to know how to link that dataset to the ultraGrid. the links about use the code

```
UltraGrid1.DataSource = DataSet
```

however this doenst work with ABL. Does anyone have any ideas how to link the table data with the UltraWinGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used the infragistics grids, but generally what you'd need to do to get a grid populated is -

. Create a ProBindingSource. Use the ProBindingSource designer to define / import the details of the tables and fields you will need.

. The ProBindingSource will become the datasource for your grid, so either set the datasource property in the designer or use the syntax you have above.

. You then need to get the ProBindingSource populated. To do this you would attach either a query, a buffer or a ProDataSet. You attach it using the :handle property of the ProBindingSource. I tend to use a query, so something like -

```
define query qCustomer for customer scrolling.

open query qCustomer
    for each customer
    no-lock.

assign pbsCustomer:handle = query qCustomer:handle.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any knowledge about ABL or OpenEdge, and I am not sure what exactly is the structure of the Test object table. You could try passing it directly to the DataSource property and verify if the UltraGrid will display it correctly or not.

More information about the DataSource property of the UltraGrid and what kind of objects you could use might be found at the provided link below:

http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/?page=Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBase~DataSource.html